# Uncaught (in promise) Unable to find element in cloned iframe #2460

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, html5-canvas, html2canvas

How can I fix this error?

#### My code:

```
const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
const myHTMLString = "<div>Hello</div>";
wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",myHTMLString);
//console.log(">>>",wrapper);
html2canvas(wrapper,{useCORS: true}).then((canvas) => {
    wrapper.appendChild(canvas); 
    console.log("canvas>>",wrapper.appendChild(canvas));
    var base64encodedstring = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
    console.log("base6", base64encodedstring );
});
```

#### Error:

[image]

> 176e275da87 1ms Starting document clone
> Uncaught (in promise) Unable to find element in cloned iframe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The html2canvas [documentation](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation) says (I highlight in bold):

> The script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of it, directly on the users browser. The screenshot is **based on the DOM**
> [...]
>
> The script traverses through **the DOM of the page it is loaded on**. It gathers information on all the elements there, which it then uses to build a representation of the page. In other words, it does not actually take a screenshot of the page, but builds a representation of it based on the properties it reads **from the DOM**.

This all means that the argument you pass to `html2canvas` must be an element that is present in the document. This explains the (uncaught) error you got:

> Unable to find element in cloned iframe

Apparently this tool creates a temporary `iframe` in which it clones the document. Then it will search the element you passed as argument. Since in your case `wrapped` is not part of the document, this search fails.

So before calling `html2canvas` you could do:

```
 document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
```

And then if you don't want it to stay in the DOM, remove it again as soon as you have the canvas rendering.